# Solving a recurrence with 2 recurrences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, recursion

I am trying to solve the following recurrence:
$$T(n) = T\Big(\frac{n}{3}\Big) + T\Big(\frac{2n}{3}\Big) + O(n)$$

I do not want to use the Akra-Bazzi method nor draw out a recurrence tree. I do know that the solution should be $n\log n$ but what is a way in which I could prove this? Intuitively to me it seems that it should be $O(n)$ Is there any other way to which I could solve this?

EDIT: I want to solve this recurrence in order to compare it to $T(n) = T\big(\frac{n}{5}\big) + T\big(\frac{7n}{10}\big) + O(n) = O(n)$ and why these two recurrence relations have different runtimes

Comment: What about the [substitution method](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/recitations/rec19.htm)?

Comment: I would prefer not to use the substitution method. To better understand why this recurrence is $O(n\log n)$ and not $O(n)$

Comment: The reason why the second recurrence has time O(n) is that 1/5 + 7/10 < 1.

Comment: You do not need to draw the whole recurrence tree; you can just draw the recurrence tree for two levels. You will find that the cost associated with each level is the same for $T(n) = T(\frac{n}{3}) + T(\frac{2n}{3}) + O(n)$, but the cost associated with each level is decreasing for $T(n) = T(\frac{n}{5}) + T(\frac{7n}{10}) + O(n)$. That's why their results are different.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Akra-Bazzi? Do you need a shaper result?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$T(n)
=T(an)+T((1-a)n)+O(n)
$
where
$0 < a < 1$.

If 
$T(m)
=O(m \log(m))
$
for $m < n$
then
$T(m) <
cm \log(m)
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
T(n)
&< can\log(an)+c(1-a)n\log((1-a)n)+O(n)\\
&= can(\log(a)+\log(n))+c(1-a)n(\log(1-a)+\log(n))+O(n)\\
&= can\log(a)+can\log(n)+c(1-a)n\log(1-a)+c(1-a)n\log(n)+O(n)\\
&= cn(a\log(a)+(1-a)\log(1-a))+cn\log(n)(a+(1-a))+O(n)\\
&= cn\log(n)+cn(a\log(a)+(1-a)\log(1-a))+O(n)\\
&= cn\log(n)+O(n)
\qquad\text{since } |a\log(a)+(1-a)\log(1-a)| \le \ln(2)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: That's basically the substitution method, isn't it?

Comment: That's how I solved it and would solve it. I don't care what you call it. Besides, how else would you solve it?

Comment: I would solve it like this. Or Akra-Bazzi's method. My comment is only about the fact that the OP apparently does **not** want to do it that way...